# Does an Ubuntu Server need swap space?

Tags: ubuntu, home-server, swap

I'm setting up a home server that will be used for backups and serving up files over the Internet with Ubuntu Server 8.04.3. Do these kinds of tasks require swap space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swap space probably won't be utilized if you have > 1GB of RAM. However, I do recommend you keep a swap partition around for safety's sake - no harm in that.

Comment: I have 1GB, but that sounds like a good precaution anyhow. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Do share your knowledge with the SU community too if you have the chance, see ya around!

Comment: Absolutely, you too.

Comment: If you've got a long-running process on your server that slowly leaks memory, swap can also help with that.